# Timer loop to constantly loop series of images [Java-NetBeans]

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, timer

I'm trying to create a loop using Java Swing Timer  to constantly cycle through a set of images (i1, i2, i3....in where n is total number of images).

Each of the images is exactly the same size and must be displayed on a Label (say, l1).

There must be a delay of ten seconds between each image being displayed.

Any idea how I can go about this without using the Java TumbleItem applet> It's seems much too complicated for a simple implementation such as mine. (Displaying special deals posters on an online storefront application for school).

I am open to this being achieved in any other way.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to create a loop using Java Swing Timer to constantly cycle through a set of images

When you use a Timer you don't use a loop. When the Timer fires you just change the image. So somewhere you would need to keep a List of the images to display and an index of the currently displayed image.

> Any idea how I can go about this without using the Java TumbleItem applet> It's seems much too complicated for a simple implementation such as mine

How is it complicated? It displays a series of images, which is close to what you want.

Yes, there is some extra code that loads the images and doesn't start the animation until all the images are loaded. So you could easily simplify the code by not worry about that. Also, there is code that does animation from from left-to-right and then right-to-left. You also don't need that part of the code. Also, there is code that configures the animation speed. Again you can hard code that.

So if you start with that example and then simplify the code you will have a simple solution. Give it a try and then post your code when you encounter a problem.

Comment: Thanks camickr. I plan on trying both suggestions. My code is to be as streamlined as possible so I think the TumbleItem (modified) will work well.

Comment: I'm trying to run the applet but I get the error message: 'Couldn't read stream from file: images/tumble/tx.gif' for each image.

Answer (score -1):

This is very simple.  Use a timer like this:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

   public void run() {
     //codehere
   }

}, 0, delayInMillis)
```

Use can use an integer to specify in image.

```
public int image = 1;
```

in the run() function, use this to switch between the image

```
if(image = 1) {
 image = 2;
} else if(image = 2) {
 image = 3;
} if(image = 3) {
 image = 0;
}
```

Now, wherever you are drawing your images, use this:

```
if(image == 1) {
  //draw first image
} else if(image == 2) {
  //draw second image
} else if(image == 3) {
  //draw third image
}
```

Comment: -1 if/else logic like that is NOT a good solution. What if you have 100 images? Also, you should NOT be using a TimerTask. You should be using a Swing Timer because all updated to Swing components should be done one the Event Dispatch Thread and a Swing Timer will fire the event on the EDT.

Comment: He said he only needed 3.

Comment: Actually the OP said he needed "n" images. But even if it was 3, this is still not the way to solve the problem with nested if/else statements.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely try this.